# Slide effect (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wonder why this isn't working as expected:

```
$(function() {

    $(".door1-trigger").click(function() {
      $(".door").hide();
      // $(".door1").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
      return false;
    });
    $(".door2-trigger").click(function() {
      $(".door").hide();
      $(".door2").show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
      return false;
    });
    $(".main-trigger").click(function() {
      $(".door").hide();
      if ($('.door1:visible')) {
          $(".main").show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
      } else {
          $(".main").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
      }
      return false;
    });

});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UePuR/36/)

I would like only the `main` shown initially, clicking on `door 1` slides the appropriate container from left, and clicking `door 2` slides the door2 container from right.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: can you demo this in jsfiddle? or maybe share some html? it is a bit unclear

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UePuR/36/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were a few issues here, I had trouble with the fiddle styling for whatever reason, just moved it to jsbin to save time.  The first issue is here:

```
if ($('.door1:visible')) {
```

This will *always* be true, since it's not falsy, you need to add a [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) on there to see if it found any elements, like this:

```
if ($('.door1:visible').length) {
```

The other issue is you were hiding it with `$(".door").hide();` *before* checking the visibility, instead move it to the end and don't hide the door you want to show, like this:

```
if ($('.door1:visible').length) {
  $(".main").show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
} else {
  $(".main").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
}
$(".door:not(.main)").hide();
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsbin.com/isodo4/2).

Comment: Great, works like I wanted! But it still doesn't feel like those slideshows/content sliders where it appears to be moving from one slide to the other, what do I need to do to achieve that effect?

Comment: @Nimbuz - there's a lot more code going on there, if you want something more complex, you'll want to go with something complex...I'm not understanding why you want to basically re-write existing plugins?